# Is there a way to set the timestamp to UTC in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, footer

I wanted to create a footer for a discord embed, that has UTC time so I created the lines in the following, and then it errored a lot, so I turned it into an object / {}. Then I got this "  if (typeof data !== 'string') throw new error(errorMessage);
^
RangeError [EMBED_FOOTER_TEXT]: MessageEmbed footer text must be a string.
at reply (C:\Users\Eb482\OneDrive\Desktop\bot\app.js:219:10)"
here is my code

```
 let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setThumbnail(serverIcon)
        .setTitle(message)
        .setFooter({name: new Date(Date.now()).toISODateString})
        .setAuthor(author1);
    if (Fields) embed = embed.setFields(Fields);
    if (EmbedFile) embed = embed.setImage(EmbedFile);
    interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: ephemeral, components: components });
}
```

Please if anyone knows how to fix the error let me know.(on discord v13)

Answer (score 0):

add `.setTimestamp();` after the setAuthor, it would show the user their local time

```
let embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setThumbnail(serverIcon)
    .setTitle(message)
    .setFooter({name: new Date(Date.now()).toISODateString})
    .setAuthor(author1)
    .setTimestamp();
if (Fields) embed = embed.setFields(Fields);
if (EmbedFile) embed = embed.setImage(EmbedFile);
interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], ephemeral: ephemeral, components: components });
```

}

Answer (score -2):

Message footer has no `name` attribute. It has `text` attr.

[More on docs](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor)

Comment: That is not the answer to the question, and does not attempt to answer the question. Please focus on answering questions in the answers section, and adding comments for commenting and suggestions.

Comment: This is the solution of this error. Am i wrong? Let me know if you know right answer of this question.

Comment: It isn't a solution when you are just adding a comment though. Use comments for that, or provide code if you would like it to be a solution.